# What is the function of a Thunderbolt gigabit ethernet + USB 3.0 adapter if Thunderbolt 1/2 does not provide USB functionality?

Tags: usb, thunderbolt

What is the function of this device: A Kanex “[Thunderbolt Gigabit Ethernet + USB 3.0 Adapter](https://www.kanex.com/thunderbolt-gigabit-ethernet)?”

According to the accepted answers of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344318/thunderbolt-1-usb-compatibility) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227678/how-to-convert-the-cable-in-my-photo-to-usb/227698#227698) question, Thunderbolt 1/2 does not provide any USB functionality. Is this product a scam or do I miss something here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the function of [this](https://www.kanex.com/thunderbolt-gigabit-ethernet) device, a Thunderbolt 1/2 to USB 3.0 USB (and Ethernet) Adapter?

It is a USB Gigabit Ethernet adapter since it does not take any additional product design effort, the manufacturer added a USB 3.0 port.  **The ethernet adapter is actually a USB device, and so you basically have a fancy Thunderbolt to USB adapter, which has an ethernet adapter as an additional feature.**

> Is this product a scam or do I miss something here?

The product is real.  The answer you received from your [other](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344318/thunderbolt-1-usb-compatibility) question, only was in reference to plugging in USB devices directly into a Thunderbolt port, the USB device is being plugged into a USB port (connected to the adapter's PCB).  Your [second](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227678/how-to-convert-the-cable-in-my-photo-to-usb/227698#227698) link question provides examples of Thunderbolt to USB adapters.

Comment: My conclusion about the ethernet device is based on experience, I have no way to confirm that is the case, since I don't have the hardware in question.

Comment: In general even internal peripherals that come on devices like MacBooks nowadays are all connected via an internal USB hub; USB from a technical standpoint but no explicit hub or connector from the user perspective. So your assumption is legit.

Comment: @JakeGould - I knew at that device was a Thunderbolt to a USB device, what I didn't know for sure is if the ethernet adapter was a USB device or a Thunderbolt device, in theory, the performance could be different

Comment: Thunderbolt 1/2 to USB adapters exists.  As I explained, the answer you linked to, only indicated that you cannot plug a USB cables directly into a Thunderbolt 1/2 ports. **I can only answer questions asked in the body of this question.**

Comment: @CJLM This hardware was designed **precisely** because thunderbolt has no "usb functionality". The *whole point* of an adapter is to connect two things that, by themselves, are incompatible!

Comment: @JörgWMittag Read all references in the question